# search results from two API's

Tags: reactjs, search, react-hooks, use-effect

I would like to get data from two API on my search page. 
Can i use Promise.all()? and how to do it?

```
// npm i react-filter-search

   const SearchPage = (props) => {
            useEffect(() => {
                fetch(' https://heka4.apache.techcollege.dk/api/ingredients/')
                      .then(response => response.json())
                      .then((data) => {setData(data)
                        setSearchWord(props.match.params.searchWord)
                    setLoader('done')});
            }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Promise.all` basically behaves just like each promise itself would, but returns an array of the results in the order of the provided promises.
This would look something like this:

```
const source1 = fetch('https://heka4.apache.techcollege.dk/api/ingredients/');
const source2 = fetch('...');
Promise.all([source1, source2])
.then((allResponses) => allResponses.map(singleResponse => singleResponse.json()))
.then(([result1, result2]) => {
  // Do what you want with the two responses.
});
```

If your desired outcome is, that the faster of the two is used, e.g. for some form of load balancing, there also is `Promise.race` that only goes forward with the first response.

Another option would be to use `Promise.allSettled`, especially if you are not sure if all requests are successful. A difference to `Promise.all` is, that it wraps the result in an object that describes the status of the response like so: `{ status: "fulfilled", value: '<result>' }` or `{ status: "rejected", value: '<result>' }`